# "Waiting for Telemetry..." message in Substrate local telemetry frontend

Tags: frontend, telemetry

I compiled and am running the binaries for backend's telemetry_core (at default port 8000) and telemetry_shard (at default port 8001) as systemd units in my server, they are nicely connected to each other and they are receiving all "submits" from a polkadot node running in the same server too.

However, after launching the frontend with `yarn start` in the same server, and opening the remote "localhost port" in my local browser (via SSH), I get the following screen with the "Waiting for telemetry..." message, nothing else seems to happen:
[image: Waiting for Telemetry Screen]

The browser's console shows the following error:

```
Connection.ts:108

WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/feed' failed: 

(anonymous) @ Connection.ts:108

socket @ Connection.ts:85

trySocket @ Connection.ts:92
```

Please note that I am connecting to my server via SSH and I am translating the remote port 3000 into my PC's 4000, in case you wonder about the odd url in the picture :D

The terminal with the `yarn start` command shows:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view @dotstats/frontend in the browser.

  http://localhost:3000/
 
Note that the development build is not optimized. To create a
production build, use yarn build.
```

And when trying to build, I get the following dump:

```
yarn run v1.22.18 $ react-scripts-ts build Creating an optimized
production build... Starting type checking and linting service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit ts-loader: Using
typescript@4.4.2 and
/home/telemetry/substrate-telemetry/frontend/tsconfig.prod.json Failed
to compile.

Failed to minify the bundle. Error: static/js/main.4c691ad1.js from
UglifyJs Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /home/telemetry/substrate-telemetry/frontend/node_modules/react-scripts-ts/scripts/build.js:127:23
    at /home/telemetry/substrate-telemetry/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:269:13
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/home/telemetry/substrate-telemetry/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:375:38)
    at /home/telemetry/substrate-telemetry/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:262:10
    at /home/telemetry/substrate-telemetry/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:368:12
    at next (/home/telemetry/substrate-telemetry/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:218:11)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/home/telemetry/substrate-telemetry/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/performance/SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
    at next (/home/telemetry/substrate-telemetry/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:220:14)
    at /home/telemetry/substrate-telemetry/frontend/node_modules/sw-precache-webpack-plugin/lib/index.js:98:18
Read more here: http://bit.ly/2tRViJ9

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Do you have any suggestions for troubleshooting? What may be going wrong here?

Comment: what software are you using? https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-telemetry I assume?

Comment: Do you have a backend running as described here? The names are different https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-telemetry#terminal-1--2---backend

Comment: Dear Dan, thanks for your questions: 1) yes, I cloned  github.com/paritytech/substrate-telemetry, compiled the backend and ran the frontend without changes, and 2) you are correct, my wording was wrong and I have corrected them in the original question. Any advise will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the questions from Dan, I found the problem to be in my SSH connection to the remote server: I was tunnelling port 3000 only (frontend), but the front end needs a local connection available to the telemetry_core service (port 8000), as shown in the browser error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/feed' failed

So,  tunnelling both ports 3000 & 8000 to my local host solved the problem:

[image]